# TextField and Password field not being detected

Tags: java, swing, textfield

Need to help knowing the reason why the textfield and password field is not being detected? So this is where I see the error (the red lines on txtUsername and PW)

```
private void btnLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if(txtUsername.getText().length()==0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill up blank field/s!");
    }
    else if(PW.getPassword().length==0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill up blank field/s!");
    }
    else {
        String user = txtUsername.getText();
        char[] pass = PW.getPassword();
        String pwd = String.copyValueOf(pass);
        if(validate_login(user,pwd))
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct Login Credentials!");
        else 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Login Credentials!");
    }
}
```

Before i put this code:

```
private boolean validate_login (String username, String password) {
    try {
            Class.forName(".com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/logins" + "user=root&password=");
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("Select * from admin where username=? and password=?");
            pst.setString(1, username);
            pst.setString(2, password);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()) {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
    }
      catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }    

    }
}
```

It doesnt have any error. Now its giving me lots of errors since i've put that code but that method alone doesnt have errors in it. Can you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: First, catch your exception properly and show us an error.

Comment: Where do you define these variables? Put all your class here

Comment: Only have 1 class, and those are TextField, you can simply call them without declaring right? Since technically they are already declared by the swing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your validate_login method, there is unnecessary curly brace. Remove the bottom brace

Comment: Actually you have corrected my error now. -.- Oh god, i forgot how important checking misc braces -.- But is now giving me a different error. But, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public Login() {
    initComponents();
}
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtUsername = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    PW = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
    btnCancel = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnLogin = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 153));
    jPanel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel1.setText("Password: ");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel2.setText("Username: ");

    txtUsername.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    txtUsername.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            txtUsernameActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnCancel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    btnCancel.setText("Cancel");
    btnCancel.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnCancelActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnLogin.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    btnLogin.setText("Login");
    btnLogin.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnLoginActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(27, 27, 27)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 77, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(btnLogin)
                            .addGap(61, 61, 61)
                            .addComponent(btnCancel))
                        .addComponent(PW)))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 77, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(txtUsername)))
            .addContainerGap(32, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(91, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(txtUsername, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(PW, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(btnCancel)
                .addComponent(btnLogin))
            .addGap(91, 91, 91))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if(txtUsername.getText().length()==0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill up blank field/s!");
    }
    else if(PW.getPassword().length==0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill up blank field/s!");
    }
    else {
        String user = txtUsername.getText();
        char[] pass = PW.getPassword();
        String pwd = String.copyValueOf(pass);
        if(validate_login(user,pwd))
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct Login Credentials!");
        else 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Login Credentials!");
    }
}
```

Comment: `new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 12)` that isn't likely to work on a machine that is not MS Windows.  In that the `Trebuchet MS` font will not be installed.